# Условная конструкция if в условной конструкции if - как вернуться из второй по вложенности в первую?

Tags: python-3.x, if

Я подготовил немного кода - хочу на примере объяснить, что мне непонятно:

```
print("Добро пожаловать на тестовое пространство")
print("Сейчас вы находитесь в 'начальной точке А'")
print("Вы можете переместиться в любом из 4 направлений")

location = input("введите направление [север/юг/запад/восток] ")

if location == "север":
    print("вы переместились на север") 
    dalee = input("теперь выберите высоту [вверх/вниз] или напишите [назад] дабы вернуться к выбору направления ")

    if dalee == "вверх":
        print("теперь вы чуть выше")
    elif dalee == "вниз":
        print("теперь вы чуть ниже")
    elif dalee == "назад":
        print("как вернуться я не знаю...")
    # как на этом этапе прервать условную конструкцию if с выбором высоты
    # и вернуться к конструкции if с выбором направления?

elif location == "юг":
    print("вы переместились на юг")
    dalee = input("теперь выберите высоту [вверх/вниз] или напишите [назад] дабы вернуться к выбору направления ")

    if dalee == "вверх":
        print("теперь вы чуть выше")
    elif dalee == "вниз":
        print("теперь вы чуть ниже")
    elif dalee == "назад":
        print("как вернуться я не знаю...")
    # как на этом этапе прервать условную конструкцию if с выбором высоты
    # и вернуться к конструкции if с выбором направления?

elif location == "запад":
    print("вы переместились на запад")
    dalee = input("теперь выберите высоту [вверх/вниз] или напишите [назад] дабы вернуться к выбору направления ")

    if dalee == "вверх":
        print("теперь вы чуть выше")
    elif dalee == "вниз":
        print("теперь вы чуть ниже")
    elif dalee == "назад":
        print("как вернуться я не знаю...")
    # как на этом этапе прервать условную конструкцию if с выбором высоты
    # и вернуться к конструкции if с выбором направления?

elif location == "восток":
    print("вы переместились на восток")
    dalee = input("теперь выберите высоту [вверх/вниз] или напишите [назад] дабы вернуться к выбору направления ")

    if dalee == "вверх":
        print("теперь вы чуть выше")
    elif dalee == "вниз":
        print("теперь вы чуть ниже")
    elif dalee == "назад":
        print("как вернуться я не знаю...")
    # как на этом этапе прервать условную конструкцию if с выбором высоты
    # и вернуться к конструкции if с выбором направления?
```

Comment: Нифига не понятно. Может в `while True:` обернуть?

Comment: Как обернуть в while True я не знаю. Возможно у вас есть пример как применить цикл while? Я очень плохо знаю python. Я пытался объяснить как умею - суть в том, что пользователь совершив выбор, должен иметь возможность отменить его и "перевыбрать". 

Может даже вернуться на определённую строчку где начинается самый первый if